# R - dplyr - help for .[ ] and .$

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some idea as to how to select columns using .[] and .$ in dplyr.

Here is a reprex:-

```
library(dplyr)
> mtcars%>% .["disp"] %>% head
                  disp
Mazda RX4          160
Mazda RX4 Wag      160
Datsun 710         108
Hornet 4 Drive     258
Hornet Sportabout  360
Valiant            225
> mtcars%>% .$"disp" %>% head
[1] 160 160 108 258 360 225
>
```

I wish to read the help page the .[] and .$ 
How can I do this ? My googling was not successful so I came here. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

I am using this inside mutate.

```
> library(dplyr)
> names(mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"
> chosen_cols <- c("disp","drat")
> library(dplyr)
> mtcars %>% mutate(answer = rowSums(.[chosen_cols]))
```

Here is how we can select rows :-

> mtcars %>% head %>% .[1,]

```
          mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use .[] or .$ rather than dplyr::mutate ? Could you give us insights?

Comment: You don't need `[` or `$` in `dplyr` most of the time . As far as answer to your question is concerned you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Comment: `mtcars%>% .[["disp"]] %>% head`. VTC as duplicate.

Comment: I do have some idea of how to USE .[] and .$ ,I am not able to access the help page for them. That page pointed to by @RonakShah does NOT say how .[] can be used to select columns which is what I am doing. Can someone show me how to read the help page for .[] in the context of selecting columns

Comment: linog, please see my edit in response to your query.

Comment: Help page for all are present in `?Extract` and this works as expected right? `mtcars %>% mutate(answer = rowSums(.[chosen_cols]))`

Comment: It does seem to work as expected,I have another related query    .[chosen_cols] selects *columns*, how can I select *rows* using . notation

Comment: Answered this query by editing the original query, please see above.